# Show DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in 3d Style

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I was planning to make the DataGridViewComboboxCell to display similar to a 3D Fixed Style of a textbox. I manage to do it with a Combobox using this code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        cmbbox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        cmbbox.DrawItem += ComboBox_DrawItem_3DFixed;
    }

    private void ComboBox_DrawItem_3DFixed(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;

        e.DrawBackground();
        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Focus)
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();

        var index = e.Index;
        if (index < 0 || index >= cmb.Items.Count)
            return;

        var item = cmb.Items[index];
        string text = (item == null) ? "(null)" : cmb.GetItemText(item);
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it with the DataGridViewComboboxCell. Tho I did found a solution here:

```
    public void Form1()
    {
        dgView.CellPainting += dgView_EditingControlShowing;
    }

    void dgView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)e.Control;
            cb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            cb.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(ComboBox_DrawItem_3DFixed);
        }
    }
```

But the problem with this, it only changes the appearance of the DataGridViewComboboxCell when the specific cell is clicked, and when it lose focus, it returns back to normal.

I did find the CellPainting Event, but I don't know how it works for this code. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a 3D style `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` You should perform these 2 settings:

1. You should disable visual styles for combo box editing control
2. You should draw combo box cell yourself and draw a 3d combo button

To do so, handle `EditingControlShowing` and `CellPaint` event:

```
[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, String pszSubAppName, String pszSubIdList);
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        SetWindowTheme(e.Control.Handle, "", "");
}
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
    {
        var r1 = e.CellBounds;
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, r1);
        r1.Width --;
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, r1, Border3DStyle.Sunken);
        e.Paint(r1, DataGridViewPaintParts.Border |
            DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
        var d = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
        var r2 = new Rectangle(r1.Right - d - 2, r1.Top + 2, d, r1.Height - 5);
        ControlPaint.DrawComboButton(e.Graphics, r2, ButtonState.Normal);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Also to create below appearance, without any customization code, it's enough to set `DisplayStyle` of your column to `ComboBox`:

[image]

Comment: That looks great, but is there a way where I can change the appearance of the ControlPaint.DrawComboButton, it looks like it's 3D Fixed.

Comment: You wanted it to be 3D. Didn't you?

Comment: I actually want to do the appearance on the top one of the image, the one below is what I got. Image here: https://i.imgsafe.org/6467d94258.jpg

Comment: To show that style, you don't need any custom code, just set `DisplayStyle` of column to `ComboBox`.

Comment: I used your code and it seems to output this one. It also displays strange when clicking the cell. Thanks for the support so far. :)

Link Here: https://i.imgsafe.org/6555ad8ddc.jpg

Comment: You're welcome :) It seems you need the second option.

Comment: About first option, you can draw the combobox in the size of an actual combo box. The answer contains the core of solution and you may need to do some manipulation with the code :)